# Pegar Filhos sem Pai em uma estrutura hierárquica MYSQL

Tags: mysql

Tenho uma tabela com a seguinte estrutura

```
|id|parent_id|name|
```

Em algum momento, por um erro de programação, alguns pais foram apagados e ficaram os filhos.

Então eu preciso criar uma query para buscar todos esses filhos.

Eu testei essa query:

```
SELECT filha.id, filha.name FROM filha WHERE (SELECT pai.id, pai.name FROM pai WHERE pai.id = filha.pai_id) = NULL
```

Porém minha estrutura é na mesma tabela.

Comment: O que nessa tabela diz que o item é filho ? o que o item é pai? vago nesse aspecto? é um auto relacionamento, mas, como funciona no seu caso

Comment: Só complementando os questionamentos do Virgilio, dê um exemplo do que tem na sua tabela e com esses dados o que você deseja ter de retorno

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Em primeiro lugar bastaria colocar uma restrição de chave estrangeira em sua tabela que tal erro não ocorreria.

Tente

```
SELECT id_parent, id, name FROM sua_tabela a
    WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM sua_tabela b WHERE b.id = a.parent_id);
```

Comment: Perfeito! Exatamente isso.

Comment: Obrigado, me ajudou bastante!

Comment: Se resolveu o problema você pode aceitar a resposta dele conforme indica a imagem: https://i.stack.imgur.com/eyLkG.jpg

Answer (score 3):

Você pode consultar todos os registros que tem `parent_id` que não está na mesma tabela utilizando [`NOT IN`](https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/comparision-functions-and-operators/not-in.php).

> ## Atenção
>
> Você falou que é a mesma tabela, mas está colocando nomes diferentes na query, `pai` e `filha`.

Considerando que é a mesma tabela e o nome dela é `pai`a *query* é essa:

```
SELECT id, name FROM pai WHERE parent_id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM pai);
```

Se for outra tabela a *query* é

```
SELECT id, name FROM filha WHERE parent_id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM pai);
```

Answer (score 2):

Sendo a mesma tabela, caso houvesse a chave estrangeira do auto-relacionamento, a exclusão não seria possível.

Como houve a exclusão, entendo que os códigos dos "registros pais" ainda estão nos "registros filhos", sendo assim, tente isso:

```
SELECT filha.id, filha.name 
  FROM tabela filha 
 WHERE not exists (SELECT pai.id FROM tabela pai WHERE pai.id = filha.parent_id)
```